# call middleware in specific routing scope cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0, middleware

I had created a custom middleware and try to use in a specific routing scope under `Cases` in cakephp 3.5.x,

Requirement:

**routes.php**

```
use Api\Middleware\CasesMiddleware;

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

    $routes->registerMiddleware('CasesRequired', new CasesMiddleware());

    Router::scope('/Cases', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->applyMiddleware('CasesRequired');
    }
}
```

But this is not working. But when i put `$routes->applyMiddleware('CasesRequired')`, outside routing scope `cases` then its working like below,

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

    $routes->registerMiddleware('CasesRequired', new CasesMiddleware());
    $routes->applyMiddleware('CasesRequired');

    Router::scope('/Cases', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

    }
}
```

Please suggest what is going wrong.......Middleware should be called only under routing scope `Cases`.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Api\Middleware\CasesMiddleware;

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

    $routes->registerMiddleware('CasesRequired', new CasesMiddleware());

    $routes->scope('/Cases', function ($routes) {
        $routes->applyMiddleware('CasesRequired');
    }
}
```